# IOS: Convert a NSDate object into a string to get the current time

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, outputstream

I'm Using NSOutputStream to output data from the client (IOS device) To the server (PC Device). 
In the following code I'm Outputting some data using outputStream and(this code is working 100% )

```
 NSString *response  = @" Today's Sunny  \n  ";
 NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[response dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
 [outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
```

I would like to do the same thing using **Outputstream** to output the current time like (09:24.00) in this format (hh:mm:ss)

Here what i have tried

```
  NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date]; 
  NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
  [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
  //outputstream here
```

**I would really appreciate your help in this matter**

Comment: So an `NSDateFormatter` format question?

Comment: @trojanfoe yes, i'm trying to output the current time in NSDateFormatter using outputstream

Comment: There are literally thousands of questions about that on this site.  Also you need to change your question as it's nothing to do with `NSOutputStream`.

Comment: @trojanfoe agree with u,but i didn't fine something that show how to output the current time using outputstream similar to what i did in *response

Comment: It's got nothing to do with outputstream.  You know how to write a string to the output stream so your question is how to convert a `NSDate` object into a string.

Comment: @trojanfoe yes, you're correct, can you please show me how to do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111442/discussion-between-assam-al-zookery-and-trojanfoe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the date to a string and then add it to your output stream.

Use:

```
NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date]; 
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
NSString *timeString = [formatter stringFromDate:currentTime];
```

You can then send timeString in your output stream

Comment: DO you have any knolwge to solve this question for me  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37141410/ios-how-to-reconnect-to-the-server-pc-after-its-got-disconnected

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this, it has everything you need about date programming on iOS
http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/dates

**Updated** with some code samples:

Converting current time from NSDate to NSString:

```
NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date]; 
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setCalendar:[NSCalendar currentCalendar]];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"M.d.y"];

NSString *stringResult = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentTime];
```

Setting `Calendar` and `TimeZone` is optional, but if could use them if needed. You also have different optionals for them, like `NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian`, `timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:`, etc.

You have many options for `dateFormat`, for example

> M/d/y          -->       11/4/2012
>
> MM/dd/yy    -->   11/04/12
>
> MMM d, ''yy   -->    Nov 4, '12
>
> h:mm a    -->     8:09 PM

Alternatively, you can instead use `dateStyle` and `timeStyle`

```
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12294505)

Comment: @Eiko alright. updated with some code samples and explanation

Answer (score 0):

If someone need the code of Assam + Adam  in Swift, here it is :

```
var currentTime:NSDate  = NSDate.date()

var formatter:NSDateFormatter  = NSDateFormatter.alloc().init()
formatter.setDateFormat("hh:mm:ss")

var timeString:NSString  = formatter.stringFromDate(currentTime)
outputStream.write(timeString.UTF8String(),maxLength:timeString.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's the Complete answer, Thanks to @Adam

```
NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
    NSString *timeString = [formatter stringFromDate:currentTime];
    [outputStream write:[timeString UTF8String]
              maxLength:[timeString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: 12 hour clock?  Is that what you wanted?

Comment: @trojanfoe yes, time format is in 12hrs