# IOS: How to reconnect to the server (PC) after it's got Disconnected

Tags: ios, objective-c, client

I have two Applaction one is the client (**IOS device**) and the other one is the server (**PC device**). 
When I run the client it will connect to the server, and 
when I disconnect the server it will show Disconnected.

**Question: How to reconnect to the server after it's got Disconnected?**

Here's my code in the client (IOS device) side

```
     -(void)viewDidLoad{
            [super viewDidLoad];


            NSString *ipAddressText = @"192.148.211.42";

            NSLog(@"Setting up connection to %@ : %i", ipAddressText, 111);
            CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef) ipAddressText, 111, &readStream, &writeStream);
            messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [self open];
        }

    - (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {

        NSLog(@"stream event %lu \n ", streamEvent);

        switch (streamEvent) {

            case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
                NSLog(@"Stream opened");
                _connectedLabel.text = @"Connected";
                break;
            case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:

                if (theStream == inputStream)
                {
                    uint8_t buffer[1024];
                    NSInteger len;

                    while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable])
                    {
                        len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                        if (len > 0)
                        {
                            NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

                            if (nil != output)
                            {
                                NSLog(@"server said: %@ \n ", output);
                                [self messageReceived:output];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;

            case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
                NSLog(@"Stream has space available now");
                break;

            case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
                NSLog(@"%@\n",[theStream streamError].localizedDescription);
                break;

            case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:

                [theStream close];
                [theStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
                _connectedLabel.text = @"Disconnected";
                NSLog(@"close stream");
                break;
            default:
                NSLog(@"Unknown event");
        }

    }

        - (void)open {

            NSLog(@"Opening streams.");

            outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
            inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;

            [outputStream setDelegate:self];
            [inputStream setDelegate:self];

            [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
            [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

            [outputStream open];
            [inputStream open];

             _connectedLabel.text = @"Connected";
        }


    - (void)close {
        NSLog(@"Closing streams.");
        [inputStream close];
        [outputStream close];
        [inputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [outputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [inputStream setDelegate:nil];
        [outputStream setDelegate:nil];
        inputStream = nil;
        outputStream = nil;

        _connectedLabel.text = @"Disconnected";
    }

-(void)Reconnect{

   // Code here 

}
```

Comment: Call `open` in your `reconnect` if not already connected?

Comment: @bbum  Do i have to add if statement if it's disconnected

Comment: Have a  boolean `@property` that tracks connected?  Set it to YES on successful connection, set it to NO on close?

Comment: @bbum Would you please answer this question with some code. i will really appreciate it.